# Reconstructing an n-level object/array with recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript object which contains lots of properties. I need to create another similar hierarchy but I only need few properties.

```
[
  {
    _id: "559d0fcdd791e5c452345e80",
    name: "Books",
   lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:55:57.891Z",

    body: "",
    children: [
      {
        _id: "559d0fd9d791e5c452345e81",
        name: "web apps",
        __v: 2,
        media: {
          images: [
          ]
        },
        lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:09.356Z",


        body: "",
        children: [
          {
            _id: "559d0fe9d791e5c452345e83",
            name: ".net",
            __v: 1,
            media: {
              images: [
              ]
            },
            lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:25.139Z",


            body: "",
            children: [
              {
                _id: "559d0ff2d791e5c452345e84",
                name: "asp.net",
                __v: 0,
                media: {
                  images: [
                  ]
                },
                lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:34.306Z",


                body: "",
                children: [
                ],
                parent: "559d0fe9d791e5c452345e83",
                description: ""
              }
            ],
            parent: "559d0fd9d791e5c452345e81",
            description: ""
          },
          {
            _id: "559d0ffad791e5c452345e85",
            name: "java",
            __v: 0,
            media: {
              images: [
              ]
            },
            lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:42.663Z",


            body: "",
            children: [
            ],
            parent: "559d0fd9d791e5c452345e81",
            description: ""
          }
        ],
        parent: "559d0fcdd791e5c452345e80",
        description: ""
      },
      {
        _id: "559d0fe0d791e5c452345e82",
        name: "db",
        __v: 2,
        media: {
          images: [
          ]
        },
        lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:16.436Z",


        body: "",
        children: [
          {
            _id: "559d1006d791e5c452345e86",
            name: "SQL server",
            __v: 0,
            media: {
              images: [
              ]
            },
            lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:54.289Z",


            body: "",
            children: [
            ],
            parent: "559d0fe0d791e5c452345e82",
            description: ""
          },
          {
            _id: "559d101ad791e5c452345e87",
            name: "NO SQL",
            __v: 1,
            media: {
              images: [
              ]
            },
            lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:57:14.988Z",


            body: "",
            children: [
              {
                _id: "559d1025d791e5c452345e88",
                name: "MongoDB",
                __v: 0,
                media: {
                  images: [
                  ]
                },
                lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:57:25.044Z",


                body: "",
                children: [
                ],
                parent: "559d101ad791e5c452345e87",
                description: ""
              }
            ],
            parent: "559d0fe0d791e5c452345e82",
            description: ""
          }
        ],
        parent: "559d0fcdd791e5c452345e80",
        description: ""
      }
    ],
    parent: null,
    description: "Some books"
  }
]
```

From this I need to create a hierarchy like this:

```
[{
  text: 'books',
  nodes: [{
    text:'web apps',
    nodes:[{
      text: '.net',
      nodes:[{
        text:'asp.net',
        nodes:[]
      }]
    },{
      text: 'java',
      nodes:[]
    }]
  },{
    text: 'DB',
    nodes: [{
      text: 'SQL Server'
    },{
      text: 'NO SQL',
      nodes:[{
        text: 'MongoDB'
      }]
    }]
  }]

}]
```

I am trying to create a recursive loop but not sure how to add child nodes. How can I get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive function. This one is constructed for your specific data input:

```
function reduce (input, output) {
  output = [];
  $.each(input, function(key, val) {
    output[key] = {};
    output[key].text = val.name;
    output[key].nodes = reduce(val.children);
  });
  return output;
}
```

and it is called with `output = reduce(input);`

Here's a snippet:

```js
input = [
  {
    _id: "559d0fcdd791e5c452345e80",
    name: "Books",
   lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:55:57.891Z",

    body: "",
    children: [
      {
        _id: "559d0fd9d791e5c452345e81",
        name: "web apps",
        __v: 2,
        media: {
          images: [
          ]
        },
        lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:09.356Z",


        body: "",
        children: [
          {
            _id: "559d0fe9d791e5c452345e83",
            name: ".net",
            __v: 1,
            media: {
              images: [
              ]
            },
            lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:25.139Z",


            body: "",
            children: [
              {
                _id: "559d0ff2d791e5c452345e84",
                name: "asp.net",
                __v: 0,
                media: {
                  images: [
                  ]
                },
                lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:34.306Z",


                body: "",
                children: [
                ],
                parent: "559d0fe9d791e5c452345e83",
                description: ""
              }
            ],
            parent: "559d0fd9d791e5c452345e81",
            description: ""
          },
          {
            _id: "559d0ffad791e5c452345e85",
            name: "java",
            __v: 0,
            media: {
              images: [
              ]
            },
            lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:42.663Z",


            body: "",
            children: [
            ],
            parent: "559d0fd9d791e5c452345e81",
            description: ""
          }
        ],
        parent: "559d0fcdd791e5c452345e80",
        description: ""
      },
      {
        _id: "559d0fe0d791e5c452345e82",
        name: "db",
        __v: 2,
        media: {
          images: [
          ]
        },
        lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:16.436Z",


        body: "",
        children: [
          {
            _id: "559d1006d791e5c452345e86",
            name: "SQL server",
            __v: 0,
            media: {
              images: [
              ]
            },
            lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:56:54.289Z",


            body: "",
            children: [
            ],
            parent: "559d0fe0d791e5c452345e82",
            description: ""
          },
          {
            _id: "559d101ad791e5c452345e87",
            name: "NO SQL",
            __v: 1,
            media: {
              images: [
              ]
            },
            lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:57:14.988Z",


            body: "",
            children: [
              {
                _id: "559d1025d791e5c452345e88",
                name: "MongoDB",
                __v: 0,
                media: {
                  images: [
                  ]
                },
                lastUpdated: "2015-07-08T11:57:25.044Z",


                body: "",
                children: [
                ],
                parent: "559d101ad791e5c452345e87",
                description: ""
              }
            ],
            parent: "559d0fe0d791e5c452345e82",
            description: ""
          }
        ],
        parent: "559d0fcdd791e5c452345e80",
        description: ""
      }
    ],
    parent: null,
    description: "Some books"
  }
]

function reduce (input, output) {
  output = [];
  $.each(input, function(key, val) {
    output[key] = {};
    output[key].text = val.name;
    output[key].nodes = reduce(val.children);
  });
  return output;
}

output = reduce(input);
$('div').text(JSON.stringify(output));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```